# How to regulate subcategory call method

Tags: c#

I have a game project, and I need a "use skill" system.

I create a ABaseSkillMotion class, and call SkilEnd() when skill motion end.

but ABaseSkillMotion don't know every subcategory class will call SkillEnd().

I can only create a "property void SkillEnd()" method. Let sub-categories use.

but I can't regulate subcategory call method. other programer don't know need call SkillEnd() when end time.

so...

Have any Design Patterns can regulate subcategory to call method ?

e.g.

```
public class A{
    protected void onEndMethod(){
        //end !
    }
}


public class B : A{
    void Update(){
        //need call onEndMethod() when finish;
    }
}
```

PS: B class will Update many times, when last time A need B call onEndMethod(), else will timeout.

Thanks !

Comment: When you say "subcategory", do you mean an inherited class?

Comment: Since you've looked through list of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Behavioral_patterns and found nothing useful, could you please [edit] your question and clarify what exactly you are looking for and why standard patterns did not cover your case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I think he wants the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: my "subcategory" is mean B class, if that is inherited class, then yes @@

Comment: thanks AlexeiLevenkov and Icemanind, but I think "Template Method Pattern" is not enough.

Comment: @OwenHuang than you should [edit] your post to clearly explain why "template method" is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class A{
    protected void onEndMethod(){
        //end !
    }
    protected void Update(){
        DoUpdate();
        onEndMethod();
    }
    protected abstract void DoUpdate();
}


public class B : A{
    protected override void DoUpdate()
    {
      // B class specific code
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks answer, but... i'm mean A class is not know B's Update end time.
not everytime call onEndMethod()